# Trigger prefetching after page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, prefetch

My scenario is:

- user visits **domain.com** (home page)
- **domain.com/products** page contains large image library and quite large *CSS* and *JS* libraries
- when user visits **domain.com** and the **home page has fully loaded**, we start to *prefetch* resources & if possible at least some % of images from the archive.

Currently on some pages *JS* "eats" quite a lot of resources therefor triggering prefetch in some cases during page load is not the best answer - as it will cause a small lag when user interacts with *JS* created events and elements.

My questions are:

1. Is it even possible (will it work) to trigger `<link rel="prefetch" href="image.png">` or CSS file to be added to `<head>` so it can *prefetch* data from another page **after current page is fully loaded**?
2. Should I do it similar like rendering additional stylesheet using JS where I add new  tag within `<head>` as a stylesheet file so it can then render.. or is there another way?

Comment: unfortunate you had to open a bounty for this, but [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) was made for background tasks, as far as adding new stylesheets or tags to a fully loaded document, then of course. That's as simple as [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule). Naturally you will have to do other logic and DOM manipulation to refresh etc but that's just a matter of finding solutions specific to your project. Lots of tutorials/examples out there on this topic.

Comment: @soulshined I really don't care about the bounty. I just have to understand this. Yeah I was reading similar docs about this before but It's not quite what I was searching for. I don't need to *preload* I need to *prefetch* so It possibly stays on user browser and when we load the next page (as the resources have been loaded previously) it loads the page much faster and doesn't cause any small lags. Anyway, thanks for reply. I will continue to research.

Comment: I'm not getting correctly what are you trying to say! Are you trying to load external Stylesheets, js and Images after the page loads?

Comment: @AAShakil User opens domain.com. As he hasn't opened other pages and loaded resources he will have to load large amount of resources when he visits next page - therefor I have to somehow prefetch them in current page **after the current page has been loaded** - soo I have to trigger it after page load.

Comment: I get it now @RicardsMucelans . There are tutorials/ [discussions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) out there on this and some really good [blog posts](https://csswizardry.com/2013/01/front-end-performance-for-web-designers-and-front-end-developers/#section:dns-prefetching) as well. But cautionary tale, if I was a mobile user that wasted a bunch of data to preload a webpage I don't even need or visit, I would be sad when my bill comes, especially if it's as large as you say it is. But that's neither here nor there. Check those links out for some run downs

Comment: @soulshined yeah `prefetch`! haha. About mobile users - that's why I need to be able to trigger it withing specific place and after page is loaded, so I can control data prefetch for mobile devices. Not everyone has unlimited data plan, haha.

Comment: If you'r worried about mobile users, than my guess is it's safe to assume your worried about all users? If that's the case make sure you check for [compatability](https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-prefetch) and [another](https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-dns-prefetch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might use [Cache Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage) to prefetch (precache) assets. I work on an open-source project which uses [this approach](https://github.com/sirko-io/client/blob/master/src/sirko/barn.js#L60-L70). Although, to serve precached assets you need a [service worker](https://github.com/sirko-io/client/blob/master/src/sirko_sw.js#L57-L70). The logic of finding assets in my project looks like [this](https://github.com/sirko-io/client/blob/master/src/sirko/barn.js#L20-L36).

The demo of this project is [here](https://demo.sirko.io/home). Also, I wrote [an article](https://nesteryuk.info/2018/04/08/automate-precaching-resources.html) which explains technical details of the project.

Assets [get prefetched](https://github.com/sirko-io/client/blob/master/src/sirko.js#L38) once the lib is loaded, so I don't wait for the entire page load. Maybe I should use [requestIdleCallback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestIdleCallback) to wait until the browser is idle.

Hopefully, it gives you some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitriy Nesteryuk. This is really a great solution for my scenario. I love the approach of telling next possible page to be prefetched. I will definetly try this in my next project. But I am still wondering if `prefetch` can be triggered manually later after page preload - that's the main reason I posted here with bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Just to note that you could add aditional stylesheet after the page load completly or whenever you want with somethig like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
      var script = document.createElement("link");
      script.rel = "stylesheet";
      script.href= "stylesOfAnotherPage2.css";

      document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);//or head
});
```

When you load page1, `stylesOfAnotherPage2.css` is cached, so when page2 is called, `stylesOfAnotherPage2.css` is already cached if page2 call the same file.

Comment: Yes. This is the aproach I am going with currently. Thanks for the code though @Emeeus.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [HTTP Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) and [Link prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) to use your browser idle time to download or prefetch documents that the user might visit in the near future.

**Prefetching hints**

> The browser observes all of these hints and queues up each unique
>   request to be prefetched when the browser is idle. There can be
>   multiple hints per page, as it might make sense to prefetch multiple
>   documents. For example, the next document might contain several large
>   images.

```
<link rel="prefetch alternate stylesheet" title="Designed for Mozilla" href="mozspecific.css">
<link rel="next" href="2.html">
```

Also, you can read this thread:
[Preload, Prefetch And Priorities in Chrome](https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf)
There you can read the different states and priorities about the execution, load and preload times, some tips to improve them.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the sources. @Dmitriy Nesteryuk already pointed out about caching and then prefetching using his library. Both of your solutions and explanations are great solution for my scenario. But the main question that I can't seem to get answer to is **can I manually add and trigger `prefetch` after page is fully loaded**!? Anyway for the next project I am definetly using both of your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

`preload` of CSS and JS using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content might be a good fit and has good support in most modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=preload

There are probably better solutions, such as the one suggested by @soulshined, but another crude way to do this is the other page contains etags or cache control headers would be to use AJAX to send requests to the resources you expect to load. This would cause the browser to request those resources and prefill the user agent cache so that when the user requests that resource on the other page there is a higher change the cache would contain the resources and it'd load faster than if it had to fetch everything for the first time.

Comment: **You mean then load them in background, right (talking about the Ajax solution)?**

Talking about `preload` - again, it's not what I need - I need `prefetch` in this scenario as the main point of all this is to reduce next page loading time and overal pages' loading time.

[Source I found: Preload vs. Prefetch](https://medium.com/reloading/preload-prefetch-and-priorities-in-chrome-776165961bbf#89a4)

Comment: perhaps I don't follow what you mean. If page A makes AJAX requests to resources that you know to be on page B (which happen to be cachable resources). If/when the user finally tries to load page B after page A then those resources will likely be in the user agent cache which means that page B will load faster than if those resources were not load somehow "preloaded" on page A.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to acomplish. `prefetch` option in this case would be much easier and more simple to use. I think Ajax solution will be my last option to try. Thanks anyway @David Goate

Comment: Does this link not help then? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ What I mean is, on page A can you not link to various resources you know to be on page B such as HTML, JS, CSS, Images and therefore if the user clicks a link through to page B you'll know that it'll possibly be prefecthed and ready to go which will page page B load faster simple because the user visited page A first,

Comment: Of course @soulshined made the valid point that from a user experience point of view mobile users especially may be a little upset by the bandwidth usage.

Comment: I understand that but what about triggering prefetch event after load? Controlling when its going to be prefetched? I mentioned above about this that we do want to take care about mobile devices prefetching as little as possible - plus I just read that <link> option is the best way to go, as the users Browser will register event and will know what to do, but Ajax backgound requesting won't. Finally I have a little light about this - yet the question about "triggering" it still remains. Longstoryshort - `prefetch` should be used in this case & not Ajax solution or `preload`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171578/discussion-between-ricards-mucelans-and-david-goate).

Comment: Hi @ricardsMucelans I did try to reach out on the link in the private chat. Did you make any progress?

Comment: I messeged you back later that day.

Answer (score 0):

To prefetch assets there are some prefetching methods such as DNS-prefetch, pre-connect, pre-render & prefetch. As per the requirement, you may use them appropriately. Each method has its own purpose [this](https://medium.com/@soorajchandran/speeding-up-your-website-using-prefetching-techniques-8077058b7418) would be useful to know each one specifically.